# Don't count owner votes in /tools?tab=delete

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

If somebody writes an answer, deletes it, and undeletes it again, that answer will show up with one delete vote in [/tools?tab=delete](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete). This leads to the delete/undelete vote lists being flooded with such post, making it unusable. The lists get cluttered with posts I most of the time couldn't and shouldn't vote on.

Posts should only show up in the delete/undelete vote lists if somebody else than the owner cast these votes.

Comment: Hm... this wasn't so much a problem back when it was questions only. But now that answers are added there, this will indeed make it cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the same time you asked this question, we changed the delete/undelete votes to only display posts that have *ever been deleted or undeleted by someone else than their owner*.

In other words, somewhere in the deletion history of the post, someone else had a play.