# Add a Vote to Delete option on the /review page for 20k+ users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, deleted-answers

I have been following the /review page to help keep questions clean.  Until recently, the only way to clean up junk answers was to flag for a mod.  But now 20k users can delete answers.

I think that we should be able to vote to delete answers on the review page so that the 20k+ people can take care of them instead of making the mods deal with it.

(I know I could click through to the question to vote to delete, but if I am flagging 30+ times in a day, that adds a significant amount of time.)

Comment: Do 10/20k mods have access to a list of questions/answers with delete votes? Because it would be helpful if not every 20k-er has to go look for posts to finish off

Comment: @Ivo, yes.  We do have those tools.

Comment: @Ivo It replaces the old tool for delete votes on questions. Which, has its [fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78911/in-the-10k-tools-please-hide-answers-that-dont-qualify-for-deletion) [share](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78954/dont-count-owner-votes-in-toolstab-delete) [of issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78977/dont-show-10k-users-posts-they-cant-delete-in-the-delete-tools)

Comment: The more work users can do, the better

Comment: @Ivo [In theory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78126/add-mso-so-migration-path/78134#78134)

Comment: Near as I can tell, this was completed a long, long time ago...